# Error creating XA Connection and Resource in websphere. System out Log completely filled with this error

Tags: server, websphere, websphere-8

Getting below error every minute in Websphere 8.5.5 for successfully tested datasource(***abc**). Sysout Log is completely filled with below error. How to fix it?

Error creating XA Connection and Resource com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: **E: Unable to get a XAConnection from the DataSource ***abc**. with SQL State : 72000 SQL Code : 1017
*-*-*-
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
**E: SQL State = 72000, Error Code = 1,017
    ... 34 more

Comment: Were there any recent user/password updates for the *abc datasource?
If so, you may need to restart the nodeagents and JVM's for the changes to reflect, despite test connection working from admin console.

Comment: I removed both data-source and j2c credentials of *abc and resarted server still this issue is not fixed

Comment: Removing the datasource wont help, as the indoubt transaction needs the datasource to be available for recovery. Add them back and restart the nodeagents & JVM's and verify the logs.

Comment: I added the datasource back how to restart doeagent and jvm?
Now i am getting below error..XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: ""...XAException occurred.  Error code is: XAER_RMERR (-3).  Exception is: <null>

Comment: Steps to restart (for WAS ND): In WAS Admin console, go to System Administration > Node agents. Select the nodeagent and Click on "Restart" and once completed, Run "Restart all Servers on Node".  
Also, are you running on a DEV/QA server where recovery of these transactions are NOT important?

Comment: sorry, I am not able to find Node agents under "System Administration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue is caused by one or more indoubt transactions in the environment which is failing recovery. Below are the possible causes for this issue and their fixes.

**Scenario 1** : Incorrect user credentials for "Authentication Alias for XA recovery" in datasource configuration (which is most likely in your case, seeing the errors)
**Resolution** : Ensure the right J2C auth alias with correct username & password, is selected for the "Authentication Alias for XA recovery" & "component-managed authentication alias" in the datasource configuration.   If incorrect, update the credentials, save and then restart the nodeagent (in case of WAS ND) and the JVM.
For more details, see : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21260425

**Scenario 2** : The user configured for "Authentication Alias for XA recovery" doesn't have suficient privileges to perform recovery
**Resolution** : It is possible that the WAS configurations are correct, but the database user configured for XA recovery doesn't have sufficient privileges to perform recovery. This can be fixed by running the below commands in database as a **SYS** user, where <'user'> is the DB user configured in the datasource authentication alias.

```
grant select on pending_trans$ to <'user'>; 
grant select on dba_2pc_pending to <'user'>;
grant select on dba_pending_transactions to <'user'>;
grant execute on dbms_system to <'user'>;  (If using Oracle 10.2.0.3 or lower JDBC driver)
grant execute on dbms_xa to <'user'>; (If using Oracle 10.2.0.4 or higher JDBC driver)
```

For more details, see : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21196663

**Scenario 3** : Pending transactions in websphere tranlog not recovering due to some issues.
**Resolution** : In this case, the JVM can be started in recovery mode, as given below - which would help recover the transactions and restart the server.

```
#Stop the JVM
profileRoot/bin/stopServer.(bat|sh) serverName 
#Start the JVM in recovery mode, The server will stop after performing transaction recovery
profileRoot/bin/startServer.(bat|sh) serverName -recovery
#Start the JVM
profileRoot/bin/startServer.(bat|sh) serverName
```

For more details see : https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/168157/how-to-resolve-transaction-and-partnerlog-recovery.html

If this still doesn't fix the issue, there is a more **'brutal fix'** (which is **not recommended and may cause inconsistencies in the environment**).

```
1. Stop the server
2. Delete the <'servername'> folder inside profileRoot/tranlog/<'cellname'>/<'nodename'> directory
3. Start the server
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank You very much..  your last solution was the ultimate solution and was helpful....

Comment: Happy to hear that, but please note that this is not a recommended option and should never be performed in any non-dev environment without consulting IBM L3

Comment: From IBM KC : "Transaction logs should NOT be deleted if running in a WebSphere Process Server or IBM Business Process Manager environment. The WebSphere Process Server and IBM Business Process Manager systems can get into an inconsistent state because the logs are tightly coupled with information in other places like BPEDB, WPSDB, SIB messages and MQ, if it is configured."

Answer (score 1):

A good guess is that you have an in-doubt transaction that Oracle was involved in, for which the recovery manager is attempting XA recovery once every minute, failing to do so because XA recovery requires additional privileges beyond what would normally be needed to connect to the database (which is why your test connection works).  If this is the cause, you can solve this problem by specifying for the data source, a user/password for XA recovery path, which has been granted the privileges to perform XA recovery in oracle.  Here is a link to a [knowledge center document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_ds_tx_recovery.html) describing how to configure the recoveryAuthDataRef for this on a dataSource in WebSphere Application Server Liberty.  If you are using WebSphere Application Server traditional, see the section of this [knowledge center document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/udat_jdbcdatsordet.html) titled "Authentication alias for XA recovery".

Comment: I removed both data-source and j2c credentials of *abc and resarted server still this issue is not fixed

Comment: If the problem persists after having removed the data source, that is more evidence to support the theory of it being from an in-doubt transaction in need of XA recovery.  Given that you removed the data source, is this just a dev environment where you don't care about actually recovering the transaction?  If you want to continue on that path, you would also need to clear out the WebSphere transaction logs and manually resolve the in-doubt transaction in Oracle.  In any case, when you put the data source back, you'll want to include the proper auth alias for XA recovery per the provided links.